# How to achieve the variable value declared in two level

Tags: shell

I have a Unix variable like below:

```
emp_tbl=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
```

Now I have created another variable like below:

```
tablename=emp_tbl
```

Now I want to see the value 1,2,3,... using `$($tablename)` but I am getting error in it:

```
~$>emp_tbl=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
~$>tablename=emp_tbl
~$>echo $($tablename)
-bash: emp_tbl: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need indirection:

```
echo ${!tablename}
```

Read the documentation on [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) yet again (reminder to self: do thou likewise).

Your attempt using `$($tablename)` fails because the `$(...)` notation is [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), and the value in `$tablename` is interpreted as the command name and the command with the name `emp_tbl` could not be found.